# Why browser do not follow redirects using XMLHTTPRequest and CORS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, rest, cors

I am writing a web application for some service using RESTful API. The API is available at `https://api.example` and app at `https://app.example`. Simple GET requests using CORS are working just fine in Chrome and Firefox. Some method accept data via POST and return 303 code with new uri in Location header.

Preflight OPTIONS request is fine:

```
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
```

Request Headers

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:UTF-8,*;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:origin, authorization, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Host:api.example
Origin:https://app.example
Referer:https://app.example/app/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.32 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1425.0 Safari/537.32 SUSE/27.0.1425.0
```

Response Headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Authorization, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://app.example
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:3628800
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Date:Sun, 05 May 2013 15:22:50 GMT
Server:nginx/1.2.5
```

Then the actual request just stop after receiving 303:

```
Request URL:https://api.example
Request Method:POST
Status Code:HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
```

Response headers:

```
Server:nginx/1.2.5
Location:https://api.example/some_url
Date:Sun, 05 May 2013 15:27:49 GMT
Content-Type:application/json
Content-Length:0
Connection:keep-alive
Access-Control-Max-Age:3628800
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:*
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://app.example
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Authorization, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
```

By RFC user agent should follow redirects, but Chrome and FF seems doesn't behave as expected. Is it a browsers' bug or I am doing something wrong?

**update:** If I start chromium with --disable-web-security everything works fine.

Comment: What are your request headers for the 'real' request (not CORS pre-flight)? I am experiencing a very similar problem. Have you solved it by any chance?

Comment: It looks like this bug report in Chromium could be related https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=237490

Comment: @vrutberg yes it looks like exactly the same. Moreover it *sometimes* works. For example, a msdn test http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/ietestcenter/CORS/CORS_014.htm pass both in Chrome and FF. A friend of mine took exactly the same code and put on his server and it doesn't work! http://twinspect.net/cors.htm

Comment: @vrutberg I have not resolved this issue to date :(

Comment: Have you had any progress on this? I no longer think this is exactly the same problem as the one described in the bug report I referred to earlier. If I avoid making a preflight request, it works for me. The bug report doesn't mention the preflight request at all. I haven't been able to find an exact bug report on this in either Chromium's or Firefox's bug trackers.

Comment: I have created a test case which demonstrates this issue: http://dev.ubico.se/cors-redirect/

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=242478&thanks=242478&ts=1369133550

Comment: @galadog, the MSDN test uses a GET request, so that's why it works. It fails when it's a POST request.

Answer (score 16):

I've been wrestling with this, too.  It appears that 3xx redirects for preflighted CORS requests are forbidden by the spec.

http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

From the spec:

*(Step 1. and 2. detail the preflighting process. And the we come to step...)*

> ...3. This is the **actual request**. Apply the make a request steps and observe
>   the *request rules* below while making the request.
>
> **If the response has an HTTP status code of 301, 302, 303, 307, or 308**
>   Apply the [cache and network error steps](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cache-and-network-error-steps).

And then if we scroll on down to http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cache-and-network-error-steps:

> Whenever the **network error steps** are applied, terminate the algorithm
>   that invoked this set of steps and set the cross-origin request status
>   to network error.
>
> *Note: This has no effect on setting of user credentials. I.e. if the block
>   cookies flag is unset, cookies will be set by the response.*
>
> Whenever the **cache and network error steps** are applied, follow these
>   steps:
>
> Remove the entries in the preflight result cache where origin field
>   value is a case-sensitive match for source origin and url field value
>   is a case-sensitive match for request URL.
>
> Apply the network error steps acting as if the algorithm that invoked
>   the cache and network error steps invoked the network error steps
>   instead.

*(Emphasis taken from the doc.)*

3xx redirects are, however, permitted for simple CORS requests.

Comment: Note that the current CORS spec, which is part of https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/, does now allow redirects to be followed after a preflight. For further details, see the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949492/cors-request-with-preflight-and-redirect-disallowed-workarounds/39728229#39728229

Answer (score 2):

If its the chromium bug here is the possible errors on your code given by chromium suport:

1. If a same-origin request causes a redirect to a different origin,
   do not enforce access control checks for the redirect response
       itself, because the request which resulted in the redirect was
       same-origin.
2. If a same-origin request causes a redirect to a different origin,
   use the original request's URL as the origin for the new
       request do not use a unique security origin.
3. Track whether the client (i.e., XMLHttpRequest) actually requested
   that credentials be sent in the first place. When a
           same-origin    request redirects to a different origin, the original
           request will    send cookies whether requested or not, because it is
           same-origin.    The new cross-origin request should not send cookies
           unless they    were requested, so that the access control checks on
           the response    will succeed if the server granted
           "Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*".

Comment: I believe his problem was not involving a same-origin request. It was a cross-origin request having a 302 response.