# Follow redirect (302) in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, xmlhttprequest

Using `Firefox` I am trying to download some data from `Google Drive` using `XMLHttpRequest`. In the debug console it gives me `[302 Moved Temporarily]` and the data i receive is empty. How can i get `XMLHttpRequest` to follow a redirect response? Also I am using https if it changes things.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest will automatically follow the redirect. What data are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20854800/1531945 may have an answer in case it's CORS request

Comment: Be careful you may need CORS for both the redirect and the page it is redirected to (with redirects, like POST's, it might not work at all, see the linked answer in the other comments).

Answer (score 7):

Basiclly you get the Location using `xhr.getResponseHeader("Location")`. In this case you could just send another `XMLHttpRequest` to this location using the same parameter:

```
function ajax(url /* ,params */, callback) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      // return if not ready state 4
      if (this.readyState !== 4) {
        return;
      }

      // check for redirect
      if (this.status === 302 /* or may any other redirect? */) {
        var location = this.getResponseHeader("Location");
        return ajax.call(this, location /*params*/, callback);
      } 

      // return data
      var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      callback(data);
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```