# How to post a result through AJAX in CasperJS when the API is responding with a 302 redirect

Tags: ajax, redirect, phantomjs, casperjs, http-status-code-302

I need to post result with Ajax, but the API I'm posting to uses 302 redirect to display results. Ajax won't follow the redirect, so I can never get my data. I just get a null response.

I can do a `casper.open()` and then it will at least post and follow to get results, but I don't want to navigate off page to get this result.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

According to the question [Why browser do not follow redirects using XMLHTTPRequest and CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386148/why-browser-do-not-follow-redirects-using-xmlhttprequest-and-cors) this may be related to the problem with a cross-domain request and preflight checks.

The solution would be to run CasperJS with the `--web-security=false` option which [PhantomJS provides](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html):

```
casperjs --web-security=false script.js
```

---

Another possibility is to open a new tab/window. A `casper` instance manages only one main page (and multiple popups or child windows). If you're not in the test environment of CasperJS, then you can create a second `casper` instance and navigate to the other page. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24883847/1816580) provides a drop-in solution for this with a usage example.

Comment: I have tried with web-security=false set but still getting null. It works perfectly in PH 1.98 but 2.0 is where it seems to have issues. Not sure if its a bug or what.